# Creating App ID in Apple Developer Portal

Tags: ios, xcode9, app-id, apple-developer

I received an error when submitting my build for Review. This is an app that is already live and supports Apple Watch. After some iterations, I had to change the bundle identifier to get the application to run, but when trying to revert it, I am unable to.I cannot create the app id in the developer portal for the bundle identifier that I need. I get the error

"An App ID with "***" is not available. Please enter a different string."

The problem is this ID is not on my list of App IDs. So my problem is that I cannot submit this application to the App Store and I cannot create the App ID with the correct bundle identifier that I need to submit this application. I am stuck here and unable to submit my application.

Any ideas here? Thank you in advance

[Error in iTunes Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjZEL.png)

[Error in Apple Developer Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH2Sc.png)

Answer (score 0):

The id my may be taken by other developer anyware it shouldn't be in your own list bundle-ids are unique for any ios app try reverse-domain name

```
 com.company.AppName
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The ID is under my company name and formatted as such "com.company.appname.watchkitapp" it would be highly unlikely that someone else to use the same App ID for Apple Watch Kit. I also already have this App ID being used in the live application, but for some reason, it doesn't show up on my list of App IDs and it also won't let me create it, which is the problem.